# Eureka Register multiple instances from one spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have a spring boot application which interfaces devices. Let's say they are printers. Obviously each printer can handle one task at a time. I may have two printers connected to one host. I may have another host with other printers connected to it.

I want the printers to be registered to an Eureka server. I want to load balance based on the printers connected not the hosing application. If I load balance the application itself, I will need to have a load balancing logic in the host application too.

How do I manually register 'instances' to eureka server from a spring boot application?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and it turns out registering more than one instance of an application isn't straight forward. The problem I found is that, at least as of Eureka Client 1.9.3, the `DiscoveryClient` is tied to a single `ApplicationInfoManager` object, which means it can only track a single instance at a time.

The work around I am using is to create multiple `DiscoveryClient` and manage them myself. This isn't ideal because the clients are pretty heavy objects (multiple thread pools, Jersey client, etc). And the Spring Boot Cloud Eureka auto configurations create a lot of beans automatically that I had to replicate. I've included the pertinent code below in case anyone else stumbles on this question.

First, configure the Spring Boot application to register with Eureka:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.appname=my-app
eureka.instance.instance-id=my-app:${HOSTNAME}:${random.uuid}
```

And here is the code gist for the main Spring Boot Application:

https://gist.github.com/michael-pratt/30517da70da3e00a902a40116e2f87f8